# How To Estimate Number of COVID Cases In A Congregation

Tags: probability

I have been estimating the number of COVID cases in my church congregation using a few basic things:

1. Get the 7-day average daily COVID case count for my county
2. Multiply #1 by fourteen to estimate how many people in my county are currently sick with COVID
3. Divide #2 by the population of my county
4. Put #3 into a binomial distribution as the probability of a successful trial, with 250 trials (my guesstimate of my congregation's typical weekly size) and looking for `P(x>=1)` (at least one positive COVID case in my congregation).

I see multiple places where I take a number and extrapolate from it without justification and without quantifying the possible error my extrapolation might introduce; I can remedy those as I think on this more.

Questions:

1. #1 relies on tests, and thus limits my estimation to those who tested positive with COVID. I think that if someone took the time to get tested, they are probably not attending the congregation while sick, and so I cannot use their positive test result to quantify the probability of COVID in my congregation.
2. My congregation is not a random sample from the county, nor is weekly attendance a new sampling — attendance is "sticky," in that most attendees are repeat attendees. Does that invalidate my use of a binomial distribution?
3. Perhaps my use of #1 is permissible so long as I view it as the *minimum* number of COVID cases in my county. How, then, would one estimate a *maximum* number of COVID cases? (This might require I learn a lot more stats theory because I know there have been numerous scholarly articles written trying to estimate the "true" COVID case count.)

How can I, as a layperson with basic statistics knowledge and access to easily-accessible data, fix this estimation? (Also welcome are suggestions of, "You should probably read this article: ...")

*Updated to state my questions more clearly.*

Comment: Perhaps the weakest link in your chain is the assumption that people in your church are typical of the population. Doctrines/shared beliefs/sermons in some churches are much more favorable to certain Covid mitigation measures than others.

Comment: @BruceET From what I can tell outwardly (ie., without getting personal demographics on each attendee), my congregation is similar to the county in terms of race, religious denomination, and political affiliation. That is still an assumption based solely on my informal observations, but I wonder if that would really be my biggest source of error. Might be, I'm just not sure.

Comment: The rate is low, the congregation is relatively large, so you might just as well use the Poisson distribution as the binomial. You are facing the kind of problem that epidemiologists often have to confront. The statistical methods needed are not often complex but assessing the effect of the various assumptions is not easy. The possible variation is not often captured by statistical methods alone.